# Review - Question closed as non-mainstream physics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen, non-mainstream-physics

[My question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463724/would-blowing-someone-elses-candle-out-make-mine-shine-brighter) was closed as not "mainstream physics". Could I ask for this decision to be reviewed please?

My question was dealing with the very real nature of combustion, not in any pseudo sciences. I learnt something from the answers.

If the objection is the joke "What do you mean the candles aren't literal?" that I added to the end (added only to acknowledge that I'm deliberately misinterpreting the original sign's author's intention) then I'm happy to remove that but it would make some of the answers that address this sub-question look like the answerer has gone on some un-asked tangent.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable physics question and has attracted real physics answers already, I so reopened it.

Comment: @Buzz Thank you.

Comment: @billpg Remove the joke.

Comment: @Buzz Shouldn't this be done by the community, given that it was closed by the community?

Comment: (The question was closed about 5 years after it was posted.) How did it suddenly get some attention?